# Load, georeference (from list of 2D stacked coordinates) and convert ungeoreferenced GRD files with python

Tags: raster, gdal, csv, rasterio

I have a list of GRD files that are not georeferenced, they come with a TXT file containing 2d stacked coordinates. I am wondering if anyone would know how to load, georeference and convert those GRD files to TIFF so I can mask and extract data down the road.

I have tried with Xarray without much success so I wondered if someone would know how to handle this with rasterio or gdal?

[Link to the txt file](https://github.com/ClimateMess/CANGRD/blob/main/CANGRD_points_LL.txt) - [Link to a grd file](https://github.com/ClimateMess/CANGRD/blob/main/t190001.grd)

Here are the first few lines of the text file (ignore the first column, it is just the pandas index)

```
   0   1   2   3
0   0   0   40.0451 -129.8530
1   0   1   40.1780 -129.3650
2   0   2   40.3080 -128.8740
3   0   3   40.4348 -128.3801
4   0   4   40.5585 -127.8834
5   0   5   40.6790 -127.3840
6   0   6   40.7963 -126.8817
7   0   7   40.9104 -126.3768
8   0   8   41.0211 -125.8693
9   0   9   41.1286 -125.3591
10  0   10  41.2327 -124.8465
11  0   11  41.3335 -124.3314
12  0   12  41.4308 -123.8140
13  0   13  41.5247 -123.2942
14  0   14  41.6151 -122.7722
15  0   15  41.7020 -122.2481
16  0   16  41.7853 -121.7218
17  0   17  41.8651 -121.1936
18  0   18  41.9413 -120.6634
19  0   19  42.0139 -120.1313
20  0   20  42.0828 -119.5975
21  0   21  42.1481 -119.0620
22  0   22  42.2097 -118.5249
23  0   23  42.2675 -117.9863
24  0   24  42.3216 -117.4462
25  0   25  42.3720 -116.9049
26  0   26  42.4186 -116.3622
27  0   27  42.4614 -115.8185
28  0   28  42.5005 -115.2736
29  0   29  42.5357 -114.7279
30  0   30  42.5670 -114.1812
31  0   31  42.5946 -113.6338
32  0   32  42.6182 -113.0857
33  0   33  42.6381 -112.5371
34  0   34  42.6540 -111.9880
35  0   35  42.6661 -111.4385
36  0   36  42.6743 -110.8888
37  0   37  42.6786 -110.3389
38  0   38  42.6791 -109.7889
39  0   39  42.6757 -109.2390
40  0   40  42.6684 -108.6892
41  0   41  42.6572 -108.1397
42  0   42  42.6421 -107.5905
43  0   43  42.6232 -107.0417
44  0   44  42.6004 -106.4935
45  0   45  42.5738 -105.9459
46  0   46  42.5433 -105.3991
47  0   47  42.5090 -104.8531
48  0   48  42.4708 -104.3081
49  0   49  42.4289 -103.7640
```

The assumed projection of the GRD files :

```
+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-110 +x_0=1884770 +y_0=5220000 +datum=WGS84 +to_meter=50000
```

So here is how I am getting started, I feel like it should be 'easy enough' to reconciliate the list of grid points with the open raster but I have no idea how to go about it.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio as rio

df = pd.read_csv(r"CANGRD_points_LL.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["id1", "id2", "lat", "lon"])

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['lon'], df['lat'])]

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)

rst = rio.open("t190001.grd")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create [GPCs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.control.html#rasterio.control.GroundControlPoint) from your list and then attribute the [corresponding transform](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html#rasterio.transform.from_gcps) to your raster

Something like:

```py
# GCPs
df = pd.read_csv(r"CANGRD_points_LL.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["id1", "id2", "lat", "lon"])

# TODO: you have to check if id1 == row and id2 == col
gcps = [GroundControlPoint(row=row, col=col, x=x, y=y) for row, col, x, y in zip(df['id1'], df['id2'], df['lon'], df['lat'])]

with rasterio.open("t190001.grd", "r+") as ds:
   ds.transform = transform.from_gcps(gcps)
```

NB: This will work only if your image geocoding can be described by a transform.
If not, you can reproject the GRD with rasterio and the created gcps